# How can I find out if an index has been created on a SQLite table?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am using this code to create and Index. I realize that it will not create it if it already exists but can someone tell me is there a way that I can find out if the index has already been created?

```
db2.Execute("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_History on History(YYMMDD,Mode,Quiz,CC,Deck)");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the internal `sqlite_master` table and query for your index:

```
var result = await conn.ExecuteScalarAsync<int>("SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='index' and name=?;", new string[] { "someIndexName" });
if (result == 1)
{
   ~~~
```